# hibernate namedQuery

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, named-query

I want to pass values to a NamedQuery.
I am selecting from a view and my namedQuery in xml file looks like this:

```
<sql-query name="findAll">
      <return alias="RcvrGroup" class="com.app.rcvp.model.RcvrGroup"/>
      <![CDATA[select * from abc.RCVR_GROUP_VW]]>
      </sql-query>
```

and in my DAO I just use findByNamedQuery

```
public List<RcvrGroup> findAllErrorVar(){
    return getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQuery("findAll");
}
```

Now, if i have a 'where' clause and my query looks like this:

```
<sql-query name="findAll">
          <return alias="RcvrGroup" class="com.app.rcvp.model.RcvrGroup"/>
          <![CDATA[select * from abc.RCVR_GROUP_VW where rcvr_mgr=:rcvr_mgr]]>
          </sql-query>
```

How will I execute and pass the values which returns list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query to use place holder `?` e.g.

```
  <sql-query name="findAll">
      <return alias="RcvrGroup" class="com.app.rcvp.model.RcvrGroup"/>
      <![CDATA[select * from abc.RCVR_GROUP_VW where rcvr_mgr=?]]>
      </sql-query>
```

And then pass the value as second parameter.

```
   return getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQuery("findAll", "rcvr_mgr_value");
```

**If need more than one parameters,** you may use `Object[]` as second parameter to pass the all parameter values in occurring sequence.

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<RcvrGroup> findAllErrorVar(String value){  
    return getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam("findAll", "rcvr_mgr", value);  
}
```